# External linking crypto/rc4.a fails

Tags: go

I'm having issues compiling code that deep somewhere in itself it tries to link to go's crypto/rc4 but returns with the following linking error:

```
truncated object file: /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/crypto/rc4.a: EOF
crypto/rc4.NewCipher: call to external function
crypto/rc4.init: call to external function
crypto/tls.cipherRC4: relocation target crypto/rc4.NewCipher not defined
crypto/tls.cipherRC4: relocation target type.*crypto/rc4.Cipher not defined
crypto/tls.init: relocation target crypto/rc4.init not defined
crypto/tls.cipherRC4: undefined: "crypto/rc4.NewCipher"
crypto/tls.cipherRC4: undefined: "type.*crypto/rc4.Cipher"
crypto/tls.init: undefined: "crypto/rc4.init"
```

The following are my go variables:

```
GOPATH=/home/sfines/workspace/audit_system
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
```

My Go version is : 
`go version go1.9.2 linux/amd64`

I've made sure that there is only one version of Go installed. I'm at my wits end.

Comment: How did you install 1.9.2? Did you `rm -rf /usr/local/go` first, or did you overwrite the previous install? And how did you install it? (official tarball, package)? Code to reproduce it would be great too.

Comment: It was installed a clean VM, so no prior install; installed following the go instructions...

Comment: Could you try the very same VM but with a newly extracted tarball in a completely different directory? (eg: `/home/sfines/go` and set `GOROOT` to that). Keep the install you have though.

Comment: That's got it, don't know why it got hosed but thanks.

Comment: Could you diff the two installs? My guess is the original extract got killed. You may want to check the install process and have it surface errors properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a badly-extracted Go install with missing or partial files. A fresh install (with no errors) fixes the issue.